# How can I point Freenom domain to a Heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I want to link my domain to my Heroku rails app.

What steps should I follow?  What should I enter in the following Freenom form?

[image: What should i type over here ?]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a CNAME record like so:

```
Name  Type    TTL     Target
www   CNAME   14440   appname.herokuapp.com
```

You might need to setup something different to forward apex to www to that http://yourdomain.com forwards to http://www.yourdomain.com

Comment: Please note that Heroku have changed how they handle DNS pointing - more information on their DevCenter: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Now, heroku requires a verified account which needs billing info to perform this. It doesn't cost anything though. They said its for security purposes.